# Joomla Mastodon Extension

Tags: joomla-4.x, extensions

I would like to try the extension https://github.com/nikosdion/fediverse/.

I have followed the instructions https://github.com/nikosdion/fediverse/blob/main/docs/usecase_single_author_blog.md for creating a single author blog.

But unfortunately the user of my Joomla website is not found by my Mastodon account.

The website https://webfinger.net/lookup/ shows everything correctly.

Has anyone here ever used this feature successfully?

Comment: There is this article from the Joomla Community Magazine where @Astrid takes look at the Fediverse and Mastdon that might be helpful and give you some clues where to look.
https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/february-2023/turning-the-joomla-website-into-an-activitypub-server

Comment: Thank you very much. I have read the article. That works. But the finished extension is built quite differently and I can't find the error.